# ReCaptcha validation on Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, recaptcha

on my express server, g-recaptcha-response always return nothing. This is my code at the moment:

```
    <div class=container-fluid id=mcenter>
    <form id='monitstart' action="/monitstart" method="POST">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="..." name=>
    <button class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="SITEKEYHERE" data-callback="onSubmit"></button>
    </form>
</div>
```

and on my server

```
var express = require('express')
var router = express.Router()

var request = require('request')

router.post('/monitstart', function (req, res) {
request({url: "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=SECRETHERE&response=" + req.body['g-recaptcha-response']} + '&remoteip=' + req.connection.remoteAddress, function (err, response, body) {
    req.send(body)
})

})

module.exports = router
```

And when I try to validate it, it give me a code 500 and say `TypeError: Cannot read property 'g-recaptcha-response' of undefined`

Comment: You don't have the `body-parser` in the pipeline. I would post this as an answer but chances are there is something else wrong here. Still, I bet this is the lack of body parsing middleware. Drop a note if this works I would make an answer out of this comment.

Comment: @WiktorZychla In fact it was because I had no body-parser

Comment: Does it work now then correctly and this is the correct answer?

Comment: @WiktorZychla Yup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer, accepted by the OP during the short discussion below the question involves adding the body parsing middleware (the `body-parser`) to the pipeline so that the `body` property of the request object is correctly initialized before a value is read from there.